# Что значит блок цикла в блок схеме шестиугольник i=0,5 и j = 0,5. Как реализовать в коде? (скрин приложен)

Tags: c, массивы, циклы, блок-схема

Проанализировать представленную блок-схему, сформулировать задачу и написать код программы на СИ.
Я не понимаю что значит блок цикла шестиугольник i=0,5 и j = 0,5. Как это реализовать в коде?

[image: текст]

Я написала так, но оно не работает, потому что что-то все же не так

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    
    int i, j, kol, pol, sum, st;
    int b[i][j];  
    
    for(i=0; i<0,5; ++i) 
    {
        for(j=0; j<0,5; ++j) 
        
        {
             scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    kol = 0;
    pol = 0;
    sum = 0;
    
    for(i=0; i<1,5; ++i) 
    {
    for(j=0; j<1,5; ++j) 
        
        {
            if(b[i][j] = 0)
            kol = kol + 1;
            else
            {
                if (b[i][j] > 0)
                {
                    pol = pol + 1;
                    sum = sum + b[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(pol = 0)
    printf("There are`nt positive elements");
    else
    printf("%d", st = sum/pol);
}
```

Comment: ```if(pol = 0)``` => ```if(pol == 0)```, i found error

Comment: `i<0,5` Что вы тут пытались сказать? Сейчас происходит вот что: вычисляется `i<0`, результат отбрасывается, потом `5` преобразуется в bool, и поскольку она не 0 - условие всегда истинно. Если вы хотели написать `i < 0.5` - все равно фигня получается (только одна итерация). Скорее всего `i = 0,5` на схеме просто значит `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что значит блок цикла шестиугольник i=0,5 и j = 0,5. Как это
> реализовать в коде?

Это вложенные циклы. Вот как реализовать:

```
for(i=0; i<=5; i++) {
   for(j=0; j<=5; j++) {
      . . . 
   }
}
```